# Opening a web browser in Python with Custom Settings

Tags: python

**UPDATE**

Code was answered by https://stackoverflow.com/users/6335363/miguel-guthridge in the answer's comments. My final working code:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Thread(target=app.run, args=('0.0.0.0', '8000')).start()
    subprocess.call('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --kiosk http://localhost:8000')
```

---

I am currently working on a small project that will allow two people to play UNO together online. I want to start a flask server, then open a web browser to that URL in full screen mode (Would be like adding '--kiosk' to a shortcut to the chrome executable). The reasoning for doing this would be to stop it from looking like a browser and more like an actual game. My original premise was to use 'eel', however, after every attempt failed, I went to the library 'webbrowser'. Here is what I have so far:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Thread(target=app.run, args=('0.0.0.0', '8000')).start() # To Start The flask server at http://localhost:8000
    webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.BaseBrowser("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %s")) # To register the executable for chrome
    webbrowser.get(using='chrome').open("http://localhost:8000") # To load in chrome
    # Then add some kind of option to the webbrowser which will allow it to be in fullscreen mode (kiosk mode).
```

The flask code for starting the 'server' works, and the imports are all there, however the code keeps failing and saying things like:

`NotImplementedError`

I literally have no clue what is wrong, or even how I could possibly do what I am trying to do. I also read a documentation about the 'webbrowser' import and the 'eel' import, and they both said nothing about what this error might mean or how I could accomplish what I am trying to accomplish (https://factorpad.com/tech/python/reference/python-webbrowser.html, https://github.com/ChrisKnott/Eel). I also wanted to avoid 'Selenium' as I have had bad experiences with it in the past. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Extra information for those who may be wondering:
I don't necessarily need the old code fixed, as much as I just need another way to open a web browser with custom arguments. If you could show me how to do this in 'eel', then that would truly help.

Comment: If you want to use specific flags for the web browser, you may want to use the subprocess module to create an instance of Chrome with the required arguments manually.

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge Thank you so much for that answer! Worked very well!